# Passing a function's args straight to another function

Tags: php

In PHP, is there a way to send a function's arguments straight to another function without having to specify them one by one? Is there a way to expand `func_get_arg()` so that the other function receives the individual arguments and not just a single array?

I'd like to send the arguments from `foo()` straight to `bar()` like so:

```
function foo($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)
{
  $args = expand_args(func_get_arg());
  bar($args);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes.

```
function foo($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)
{
    $args = func_get_arg();

    call_user_func_array("bar",$args);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call it on a function belonging to an instance of an entirely seperate class, that can be done by passing the first arg to `call_user_func_array` as an array.

In this example, the function `foo` accepts whatever arguments, and passes them directly into `$bar->baz->bob()`, and returns the result.

```
public function foo(/* example arguments */)
{
    return call_user_func_array
    (
        array($bar->baz, 'bob'),
        func_get_args()
    );
}
```